# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable in Python 3 when calling logging.INFO

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, typeerror

I am getting **TypeError: 'int' object is not callable** after passing an object to my class with appropriate arguments.

Is this an issue with logging or class?
Can Anyone help me with this?

Following is the Snippet:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s-%(message)s')

class employee:

    def __init__(self,first,last):
        self.first=first
        self.last=last

        logging.INFO('Employee created: {} - {} '.format(self.fullname, self.email))

    @property
    def email(self):
        return '{}.{}@email.com'.format(self.first,self.last)
    @property
    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first,self.last)

emp_1=employee('John','Doe')
emp_2=employee('John','Smith')
```

Comment: `logging.INFO != logging.info`

Comment: Please next time include the full error traceback

Comment: Sure! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 8):

[`logging.INFO`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.html#logging-levels) is a numeric value representing a logging level, it is actually the `int` *20*.

The method to log an `INFO` message is [`logging.info`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.html#logging.info), notice the lowercase.

```
logging.info(msg)
```